# error C2248: 'Gdiplus::Bitmap::Bitmap' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Gdiplus::Bitmap'

Tags: c++, gdi+

i am getting this error and i dont know why or understand the reason:

```
    vector<double> fourier_descriptor(Gdiplus::Bitmap myBitmap)
{


    vector<double> res;
    Contour c;
    vector<Pixel> frame;// = c.GetContour(p);

frame = c.GetContour(myBitmap);


    return res;

}
```

the error is in this line 
frame = c.GetContour(myBitmap);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a reference for the GetContour method, but that looks like you're trying to pass a Bitmap by value, which (if I remember my C++ correctly) will invoke the copy constructor -- and Bitmap doesn't have a public copy constructor.

If you own Contour, rewrite that function to take a `Bitmap*` or `Bitmap&` instead (i.e. pass a pointer or reference), thereby avoiding the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing it via reference:

```
vector<double> fourier_descriptor(Gdiplus::Bitmap& myBitmap)
```

Ny passing it by value, you make a copy of it, and Bitmap doesn't permit that.

Answer (score 1):

`Gdiplus::Bitmap` in non-copyable. And you are trying to copy it when you attempt to pass it around by value.